# How to make scroll animations with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, web, flutter-web, flutter-animation

How can I make scroll animations in flutter. Here is an example of what I want to create: https://www.apple.com/macbook-air-m2/. As you can see, when you scroll downwards the page is animated very nicely. I would like to create this sort of thing in flutter. Please specify if something like this will not work on any of flutters platforms.